# MySQL update field in row if it doesn't contain value

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a table that has a comma-separated list (in the form of a VARCHAR) that I want to update if a user id in that list does not exist.

I'm running the statement from a Node.js app. I'm not entirely sure how I would do it via the SQL statement. Here's what I have:

```
'UPDATE `tablename` SET `t` = "' + memberId + '" WHERE rowId = ' + id
```

That will replace the entire record. I only want to ADD the memberId to `t` if it does not exist.

`t` looks something like this: `'1652,47,245,783,2,3,55,738,2306'`;

So if I wanted to add 15 to that, it should be `'1652,47,245,783,2,3,55,738,2306,15'`;

I want to do this in the SQL statement, instead of pulling the field data and then adding it to the string in JavaScript (Node.js) and then updating the record.

Comment: Don't use comma-separated values in the first place. Normalize your schema.

Answer (score 1):

Use `FIND_IN_SET` to analyze your string value and determine if the ID is present in that comma-delimited list.

See full docs for `FIND_IN_SET` here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

A psuedo-query would be:

```
UPDATE `tablename` SET `t` = CONCAT(t, ',15) 
WHERE rowId = ${rowId} AND FIND_IN_SET('15', t) = 0
```

Of course, interpolate `${rowId}` as needed to build your query.

Comment: Would this be an issue if there was a number like 1500 or 1815 in the list?

Comment: that works after fixing a typo. What if t is blank? I don't want to insert a comma before the number in that scenario

Comment: Yes it is fairly brittle, for the reasons you point out. A better solution is  schema redesign as the other comments suggest.

Comment: Right... that's what a lot of others are saying as well. In my circumstance, unfortunately, I'm not a database person and I'm simply trying to make this work =/

Comment: Cody, what about if I want to remove that id in the list? obviously if I'm removing 15 from t, I don't want to remove/alter items that say 3015 or 1152...